# Sorting rows by the string beginning with specific letter in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Lets say i have a column bridge_code, which has values as follows

```
F001
F002
PC10
H001
H001
H003
H234
DCM0
```

All i want to do is sort above rows so that bridge_code beginning with character "H", comes at first, and rest of the code in descending order. For example i would like to return sorted rows as

```
H001
H002
H234
DCM0
F001
F002
PC10
```

Thanks
Sabin

Comment: @Sashi Kant : Its my requirement, I have to order code beginning with "H" first then rest in ascending order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ORDER BY IF(SUBSTRING(bridge_code, 1, 1) = 'H', 0, 1), bridge_code
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe using a union

like this :

```
select bridge_code from table1 where bridge_code like 'H%' 
union
select bridge_code from table1 where bridge_code not like 'H%'
```

but not recomended :p